# Is there a compiler warning is Visual Studio 2013 to detect references copied instead of assigned by reference

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value, auto

The particular case is that after a large refactoring a colleague changed

```
Foo & foo = DoSomething();
```

to

```
auto foo = DoSomething();
```

where

```
Foo & DoSomething();
```

This caused a problem whereby foo was assigned via copy instead of by reference. We caught one case. I'm curious if there is a compiler warning to detect the kind of error the above code causes.

** EDIT **

All of the answers below contain helpful and valid advice with regards to what should or should not be done. To be clear I was looking for some advice as to what can be done after the damage has occured. A rarely used compile warning would have been nice. In the end we just reviewed the code diff to see if the same mistake had been made more than once.

Comment: Deleted copy constructor. It is rarely needed anyway.

Comment: Hard to warn against what is perfectly valid code. I concur with VTT, btw. delete the copy ctor and it will flag what you seek (and likely more, but you gotta roll with that).

Comment: As @VTT suggested, just try deleting copy constructor of `Foo` *temporally* and re-build the entire project to see if there's an error, and the error is caused by the refactoring.

Comment: There's nothing to warn about, so no.

Comment: This is not a "kind of error". This is perfectly acceptable code. If you warned against this then you couldn't do something like `int a = my_vector[1]`.

Comment: In my experience; this sort of warning is usually provided by unit tests.  You do have unit tests don't you?

Comment: If there is a move constructor and the function returns by value, deleting copy-constructor won't help

Comment: Another way would be to view the diff of the refactor and look for missing `&`

Answer (score 1):

Incorrect use of `auto` is really bad for performance. I already had way to many discussions on it's usage.

My rule of thumb is to use `auto &&` everywhere possible for variables. This follows the template rules and becomes a forwarding reference.

It can be used for references, const references and returning by value.
By using this as a default, `auto` and `auto &` clearly indicate that you want a copy or you want a mutable reference.

That said, I'm not familiar with a compiler warning for this kind of constructions. I did find a clang-tidy check which looks similar: https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/performance-unnecessary-copy-initialization.html

Answer (score 0):

Your colleague is a very naughty boy. Note first that Visual C++ 2013 is **not** a C++11 compiler, although it does implement some of the C++11 standard. Notably, `constexpr` is missing.

Informally speaking, `auto` does **not** include a `&` automatically, so they essentially changed

```
Foo & foo = DoSomething();
```

to

```
Foo foo = DoSomething();
```

This epitomises the dangers of errant refactoring without adequate unit tests being in place.

The correct thing to do here was to leave the code as it is. But if the culture at your firm is such that all things new and shiny must go into a project, then the best thing is to use

```
auto&& foo = DoSomething();
```

To generate a one-off set of compiler warnings, why not (temporarily) delete the copy constructor and attempt to build the project?:

```
Foo(const Foo&) = delete;
```

Answer (score -1):

A good rule of thumb might be to use `decltype(auto)` instead of `auto` and train yourself mentally for that.

In the example provided, it will make the type of `foo` a reference to `Foo`.

Comment: Or just don't AAA :P

Comment: @Rakete1111 I am no fan of AAA myself, but sometimes the types are just too complicated to specify. `auto p = std::make_pair()` just makes so much more sense than `std::pair<Y, Z> p = ...`

Comment: I completely agree, but as I understand it OP's colleague changed types into `auto` a bit everywhere :)

Comment: `decltype(auto)` is not a good solution because it can not be combined with other type specifiers so declaring `auto const & x{...};` will grow into `decltype(auto) x{::std::as_const(…)}`.

Comment: @VTT in this particular case it is not required based on the provided code. When it is required, than certainly something else be used, but consciously. For the record, making copy constructor deleted is also not the greatest idea in many cases.

Comment: May the venerable downvoter(s) explain their downvote?